# SQL Postgres display details of edges

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph

I have a table of nodes say

```
Table Node
Column| type
------|---------------
id    | int
x     | int
y     | int
z     | text
```

for example,

```
id | x | y | z
---|---|---|---
 0 | 0 | 0 |'a'
 1 | 0 | 1 |'b'
 2 | 1 | 0 |'c'
 3 | 1 | 1 |'d'
```

and

```
Table Edge
Column| type
------|---------------
source| int references Node.id
target| int references Node.id
```

for example,

```
source | target
-------|-------
   0   |   1 
   1   |   3
   3   |   2
```

assuming a node doesn't have an edge to itself, and every source is unique

I want to display the result of the entire edge information

```
source.x | source.y | target.x | target.y
---------|----------|----------|---------
    0    |    0     |    0     |    1
    0    |    1     |    1     |    1
    1    |    1     |    1     |    0
```

I have tried many joins(self join of node with inner join with edge), (left join of edge with result of self join of node)

How can I achieve this selection result?

Comment: I would advice to include some queries you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you getting help and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want two joins:

```
select ns.x, ns.y, nt.x, nt.y
from edge e join
     nodes n1
     on e.source = ns.id join
     nodes nd
     on e.target = nt.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of PostgreSQL, you can play with the `RECURSIVE WITH` clause.

a) build a path:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
node(id,x,y,z) AS (
          SELECT 0,0,0,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,0,1,'b'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,0,'c'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,1,'d'
)
;
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
edge(source,target) AS (
          SELECT 0,1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2
)
;
WITH RECURSIVE backbone AS (
  SELECT
    source::CHAR(1)||','||target::CHAR(1) AS path
  , 1 AS hops
  , *
  FROM edge 
  UNION ALL SELECT
    p.path||','||c.target::CHAR(1) AS path
  , p.hops + 1 AS hops
  , c.*
  FROM backbone p JOIN edge c ON c.source=p.target
)
SELECT * FROM backbone;
  path   | hops | source | target 
---------+------+--------+--------
 0,1     |    1 |      0 |      1
 1,3     |    1 |      1 |      3
 3,2     |    1 |      3 |      2
 0,1,3   |    2 |      1 |      3
 1,3,2   |    2 |      3 |      2
 0,1,3,2 |    3 |      3 |      2
```

b) for the paths with 2 and 3 hops, get the first and last node id from the path:

```
-- as above, but instead of the last line: "SELECT * FROM backbone" ...
,
origin_and_dest AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  , SPLIT_PART(path,',',1       )::INT  AS origin
  , SPLIT_PART(path,',',hops + 1)::INT  AS destination
  FROM backbone
  WHERE hops >=2
)
SELECT * FROM origin_and_dest;
  path   | hops | source | target | origin | destination 
---------+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------
 0,1,3   |    2 |      1 |      3 | 0      | 3
 1,3,2   |    2 |      3 |      2 | 1      | 2
 0,1,3,2 |    3 |      3 |      2 | 0      | 2
```

With the  ultimate source id and the ultimate target id out of the path, join back to nodes:

```
-- same as above, but instead of the last line: "SELECT * FROM origin_and_dest" ...
SELECT
  origin.x AS source_x
, origin.y AS source_y
, dest.x   AS target_y
, dest.y   AS target_y
FROM origin_and_dest
JOIN node AS origin ON origin=origin.id
JOIN node AS dest   ON destination=dest.id
;
 source_x | source_y | target_y | target_y 
----------+----------+----------+----------
        0 |        0 |        1 |        0
        0 |        0 |        1 |        1
        0 |        1 |        1 |        0
```

Not quite your result, but then I don't really know what you mean by "entire edge information" ... can you be more precise?